# iterate through rows and compare the value at columns at each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that has 2 columns and 3000 rows. The columns names are `'1'` and `'2'`

I would like to add 2 more columns. The first column iterates through each row and compare the data of the columns 1 and 2 in each row then put the column name that has the highest value.

For example if at row 500, column `'2'` has a value largest than `'1'` so the new first column will have 2 in it. similarly, the new second column will have the 2nd column name of 2nd largest value.
can we make something general for any number of columns not just 2 as the I may need to increase the number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. Maybe there is some more pythonic way though:

```
df2=df.copy()
df2['highest']=0
df2['second_highest']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    l=sorted([(x, df.iloc[i][x]) for x in df.columns], key=lambda y: y[1])
    df2['highest'].iloc[i]=l[-1][0]
    df2['second_highest'].iloc[i]=l[-2][0]
print(df2)
```

Comment: There answers are useful thank you but can we make it more general to work on more than 2 columns for example of we have 10 columns can we iterate through the rows and get the max and second max

Comment: Done, i have updated the code to work with any lenght of columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the two columns directly and create a new column in the dataframe itself,

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2))
In [28]: df.columns = [1,2]
In [29]: df["Largest"] = pd.DataFrame(df[2]>df[1]).astype(int)+1

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
           1         2  Largest
0   0.315593  0.854372        2
1   0.067363  0.312327        2
2   0.650353  0.480793        1
3   0.653142  0.539709        1
4   0.077920  0.660042        2
5   0.676348  0.676716        2
6   0.252659  0.273548        2
7   0.146799  0.013372        1
8   0.891063  0.596015        1
9   0.054572  0.619679        2
10  0.311369  0.056108        1
11  0.288234  0.148597        1
12  0.056473  0.112157        2
13  0.263283  0.843832        2
14  0.098666  0.882066        2
15  0.655854  0.664619        2
16  0.873427  0.722233        1
17  0.421701  0.768081        2
18  0.303395  0.625726        2
19  0.648762  0.606731        1
```

Similarly, you can create the second column.

For a generic case, you can use `np.argsort` to rank the columns.

```
In [159]: ranks = df.apply(np.argsort, axis=1)
In [160]: ranks
Out[160]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  2  3  4  1  0
1  3  1  4  2  0
2  2  4  1  0  3
3  3  2  4  0  1
4  4  1  3  0  2
```